# Start glassfish domain without enabling or starting deployed applications

Tags: java, glassfish

Scenario: After a power outage missing a clean shutdown, a Glassfish domain will be started automatically after a reboot. Our customer would like to enable deployed applications afterwards one by one due to subsystem dependencies using the console.

We understand that a start-domain command will not only start the domain, but also start all previous deployed & enabled applications.

Is there a way to prevent the start of the applications during the Glassfish start up?

Glassfish version is: 3.1.2.9

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also looking for the same thing: start a domain without starting deployed & enabled apps.

Comment: No, sorry ... It did not seem possible by the tools given by GF by this moment in time :(